# Create a GCP metric that shows how often each endpoint is called

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I'm using Google Cloud Run to host nodejs running expressjs.  I have a bunch of endpoints that are called by a scheduler.  So basically each endpoint is a job or task.  I want to know how often each task is called.

I print to the log every time an endpoint is called `START: JobName`.  Is it possible to filter out the `JobName` and graph each job separately on one chart showing how often each job is run?

Comment: Did you try to create a custom metric? Custom metrics, also known as application-specific metrics, let you define and collect information the built-in Cloud Monitoring metrics cannot. You capture such metrics by using an API provided by a library to instrument your code, and then you send the metrics to a backend application like Cloud Monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

You could also define a [user-defined log based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#user-metrics) with a regular expression to extract a [label](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels) for the job name.

That said, the existing `request_count` [GPC metric for cloud run](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-run) can be grouped by project_id, service_name, revision_name, location, configuration_name, response_code, response_code_class, and route. that might give you the same visibility.